Getting "Error: BAD_ENCODING" in Postman response when try to send request to API endpoint
To debug this I have tried suggestion given by Postbot and troubleshooting link, However none of them work.
In this we are also sending client certificate, which is getting matched successfully as shown in console.
In console I see there is no Content-Type header. Can that be the reason?
Request:
POST  https://connect2.pointclickcare.com/auth/token
Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
grant_type: "client_credentials"
Authorization: Basic *********
Postman Console:
POST https://connect2.pointclickcare.com/auth/token
Error: BAD_ENCODING
▶
Client Certificate
 
id: "9471b913-084a-4ad7-814e-a70b7bafddbc"
▶
matches: 1
▶
key: {…}
▶
cert: {…}
▶
pfx: {…}
 
passphrase: "******"
▶
Request Headers
Authorization: Basic d******************************
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.38.0
Accept: /
Postman-Token: 3b54dcc3-3eb4-4627-8f4e-455c4ac9efcd
Host: connect2.pointclickcare.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
▶
Request Body
 
grant_type: "client_credentials"


We have no idea from the screenshot what you are sending or how. Please review the [help] and in particular How to ask as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

@triplee Screenshot have everything, Request is Post. URL is visible, All header is displaying, Auth is Basic Auth. Console is also attach to review request. Also body content is also attach. Do you want these in written text?

Indeed, we need something we can copy/paste. Please don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data. (at least not only as an image).

It looks like bug in Postman:
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/8713 This is happening when we are sending client certificate as PFX file with passphrase.

Can u try json encoding? Could be that it doesnt work with form encoding

you have to send valid token to test

check version 7.22.1
postman-portable-win64-7.22.1-35

Thank you very much, this worked for me. Now It's confirmed that this is bug in Postman updated version.
